# Remove default single quote of string .Tried replace but not working

Tags: node.js, database, excel, mongodb, data-export

```
var data = {Shop : "Shopename", email : "email@gmail.com", name : "name"},{Shop : "Shopename2", email : "email2@gmail.com", name : "name2"};

var data2exportforexcel =[data];
//wanted data
  [{Shop : "Shopename", email : "email@gmail.com", name : "name"},{Shop : "Shopename2", email : "email2@gmail.com", name : "name2"}];
```

//data i get

`[ '{Shop : "Shopename", email : "email@gmail.com", name : "name"},{Shop : "Shopename2", email : "email2@gmail.com", name : "name2"`}'];

tried replace on data2exportforexcel .but says its not a function.

I am getting data dynamically to data variable for exporting it to excel in node js mongodb using mongoxls plugin

Comment: data coming from `mongodb` should already be formatted as you expect...you need to post your actual code, with possible models you're using, etc, this example you give does not even work in javascript.

Comment: data.collection("Points”).find({'businessId': ‘shopname’ ,’_created_at':{$gt:d}}, { _id: false}).toArray(function(err, result) {

for(f=0;f<result.length;f++)
{
data = '{'+" Shop : \""+result[f].businessname+"\", Points : "+result[f].point+'}';
data = data+" , " +data;
}

//data export
 data = [data];
data = data.replace(/'/g, '');
var model = mongoXlsx.buildDynamicModel(data);
mongoXlsx.mongoData2Xlsx(data, model, function(err, data) {
  console.log('File saved at:', data.fullPath);
});

Comment: update your question with the information you put here in the comments (comments are not for this amount of code) and format it properly, it will be more clear for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
var data2exportforexcel = [JSON.parse(data)];
```

Comment: I tried ,but it gave me an error unexpected token s

Comment: I am just stuck in format while exporting data from mongodb node js to any file format . Can i use mongoexport in nodejs to easily export to csv ??